# npm package with @emotion/react with vite not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, emotion

After publishing the `npm` package the dependency `@emotion/react` goes wrong. I've used `vite` for packaging.

After installing the package to another project the `css` property shows like - `css="[object Object]`. But it should convert into a `class` attribute of the HTML.

`vite.config.ts`

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
     react({
        jsxRuntime: 'classic',
        jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
        babel: {
          plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
        },
      }),
    ]
});
```

After installing the library and using to a react project it shows like-

```html
<div css="[object Object]">
  <div role="button" css="[object Object]" tabindex="-1">
  </div>
</div>;
```

But the `css` attribute should be `class` attribute.

So, how to use `@emotion/react` to the react library project with `vite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I've changed the `jsxRuntime` from `classic` to `automatic` solves the issue.
So the config is-

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
     react({
        jsxRuntime: 'automatic', // <---
        jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
        babel: {
          plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
        },
      }),
    ]
});
```

Comment: jsxRuntime: automatic, seems to be enabled by default now per documentation https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/blob/main/packages/plugin-react/README.md however, I still see the same issue you reported.